# Deeper Understanding of Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I am trying to learn serialization and where I am not able to understand the below concept.

I have a class called Account and the class needs to be serialized, Accounts Class has two variables username and password. Of which password need not be serialized. So we are adding the keyword transient.

```
public class CustomizedSerialization{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

Account acc= new Account();

System.out.println("Serialization Started");
FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream("userDetail.txt");
ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(acc);
System.out.println("Serialization Ended");

}
}

class Account implements Serializable{
String username="myusername";
transient String password="mypassword"; 
}


Fine it runs as expected the output is 
Account UserName myusername
Account Password null
```

**The trouble starts here**. 
They say if you want to serialize the password also then write a callback methods with following signatures in the class that needs to be serialized.

Now I add this following code in my Account class

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws Exception{
    System.out.println("writeObject Callback");
    os.defaultWriteObject();
    os.writeObject(password);
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream ois) throws Exception{
    ois.defaultReadObject();
    System.out.println("ReadObject Callback");
    this.password=(String)ois.readObject();
}
```

Cool it works the job done….

```
Account UserName myusernamedurga
Account Password mypassword
```

Now my question is, we can realize this in a very simple way like removing the transient keyword for password. I believe there is some reason behind this, Can anyone explain me.

Thanks.

Comment: In this example, that is correct. **However**, *you shouldn't `Serialize` password(s)*.

Comment: Can anyone explain *what?* You added `transient` so it didn't get serialized; you added the methods so it gets manually serialized; you removed them both and it gets serialized automatically. What's the question?

Comment: @EJP, you are saying that those methods are meant for manual serialization. Can you please tell me how different is it from the normal serialization involving transient key word.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes, my question is how different are the two methods of serialization i.e by using transient keyword and by not using those call back methods.

Comment: Sigh. There are three cases. (1) What you have done with the `username` variable: default Serialization. (2) Mark a variable as `transient`: no default Serialization. (3) (3) Mark a variable as `transient` and roll your own code: manual Serialization. In this case your manual code replicates default Serialization, so (1) = (3). That isn't always true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare your class to be `Serializable`, Java will serialize all of its fields.

You can turn this off selectively for some fields by making those `transient`.

You can forgo the default serialization mechanism by implementing the `writeObject` and `readObject` methods. If you do that, you have complete freedom over how you want the object serialized.

And finally, you can mix and match: Implement the two methods, but still have Java serialize the "easy fields". To do this, you call `defaultWriteObject` from within your own implementation of `writeObject`. This will serialize all fields that are not transient for you, so you only have to worry about the others.

> Now my question is, we can realize this in a very simple way like removing the transient keyword for password.

Yes. If the default way of serialization offered by just declaring `Serializable` is good enough for you, then you can just do that.

You only need to use `transient`, `writeObject` etc if you want to customize something (for example by not writing out the password at all, or writing it out in some encrypted fashion).